# After upgrade to Snow Leopard my MacBook didn't recognize my camera (iSight)

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, drivers, webcam, osx-leopard

Yesterday I upgraded my MacBook from Leopard to Snow Leopard every thing seems fine but now it doesn't recognize the macbook pro (13")'s camera (iSight)
How can I find the driver or I must do some thing else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Run Disk Utility --> Repair Permissions
2) Reboot your system, with the left shift key down.  This will force the system to do a safe boot, and to rebuild your drivers cache and force a rescan of your hardware.

[Safe Mode Documentation](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1564)

If neither of those work, shut down, remove your battery & AC Cord, hold down the power button for approx. 5-7 seconds.  Replace the battery, and plug in your AC.  Boot up, and test again...

After all this, then maybe, it's time to Archive & Install...  But first, check System Profiler to ensure that the iSight is visible under USB devices.  If not, then it might be a hardware failure.

Comment: I hope this work for me I must try , Tanx for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Perform the following steps until it works:

1. Back up all your important data
2. Reboot
3. Fix Permissions
4. Reboot in safe mode
5. Reinstall (Archive&Install or use TimeMachine Backup as starter)
6. Reinstall (Clean install)
7. Bring the Laptop in for service

Comment: I want more easier way :P

Comment: Have you tried fixing the permissions? If this does not help, only a complete reinstall might bring it back.

Comment: Please try basic troubleshooting before you suggest and archive and install!!!!

Comment: Please use less exclamation marks! :D